# Mag.-flux build up...hate it

Tags: magnetic-fields

"An old bell ringer". After a few minutes of running, the steel pole of transformer, slowely becomes magnitized. Are there any unique metals that would prevent the mag.-flux build up, in the steel transformer?

Comment: To me, it is not really clear what you are asking. Where does the magnetic flux come from? One way to shield against magnetic fields is a “Faraday cage” made from superconducting material.

Comment: Im sorry, im looking for a certain steel, one that would not allow magnetic flux build up around the pole of transformer. Wen it runs to long, the flux build up weakens the originaly speed/freaquency at wich the bell rings along with decreasing the original amount of force that the rod hits the bell. So the bell ringer ends up slowing down and loudness decreases. The steel pole, wraped with coiled wire, is regular steel. Hoping to find unique steel that will remedy situation. Thanx Martin

Comment: I should have not listened to the “Transformers” soundtrack while reading this question. All the time I have thought about transforming cars whereas you meant a transformer. I guess it did not help that I learned those things in German, so I would have expected “Transformator”.

Anyway: So you want to make a doorbell or so with a bell, electromagnet and metallic rod? And the rod becomes magnetized and sticks to the bell?

Comment: On your question you asked, delete the word ' metallic rod' . That would be an extra componant. The electromagnet is the rod in queztion. I realize it gets magnatized off and on to make bell work. Problem is, it looses its strenth after a few minutes of ringing, due to magnetic flux buildup, in the center rod, which has the copper windings around it. I looked on this page but couldnt find any way to attach a picture to help illustrate. Is it agaisnt policy to swap email add..? I could send it that way, if you wanted? Jbb00917 the g mail store

Answer (score 0):

So you have a setup like this?

[image: like this]

And the electromagnet has a ferromagnetic rod inside? If so, and you only drive it with positive DC voltage, then the magnetization will build up. To remove the magnetization, just drive the electromagnet with a negative DC current. That will remove the magnetization again and should “reset” the magnet.

See [magnetic hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#Magnetic_hysteresis) for further reading on the “memory” of the ferromagnetic material and how to remove it.

The other way would be the usage of a non-ferromagnetic material. However, this would not amplify the magnetic field by magnetization in the material. So you would either need much more current or more windings (more voltage then as well).